# Trying to install rubber gem, Nokogiri messing it up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nokogiri

I am trying to install the rubber gem. A couple days ago, I was fooling around with Nokogiri, but couldn't get it properly installed. I forgot about it because it was not pressing. Well now I am trying to install the rubber gem and am getting these errors that confuse me and they seem to be related to Nokogiri, which is not installed to my knowledge. Help me out, thank you.

```
@THRILLHO:~$ gem install rubber
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rubber:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/noonan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/noonan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config


Gem files will remain installed in /home/noonan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/noonan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/ext/nokogiri    /gem_make.out
```

Comment: Yeah Ubuntu 10.10, I have tried installing those packages and get error messages.
I can't post the whole thing here, but
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main libxml2-dev i386 2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu0.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

Answer (score 4):

Do this: `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev` and then install rubber again

The error message is very clear: libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, lots more error messages.
I'm really struggling to see why this has anything to do with Nokogiri. I have tried removing every bit of that program's presence, but the errors are about it when I try to install Rubber. I don't think rubber relies on Nokogiri or anything. I am totally lost.

Comment: I have seen aws gems depend on libxml2. I am on ubuntu 12.10 and after i install libxml2-dev , my gem installation worked.

Comment: Rubber uses fog and fog uses nokogiri for parsing the XML most aws services use